# How can I log SQL statements executed by Flyway?

Tags: flyway

Does anyone know how I can log the sql output from Flyway?
It logs sql errors only, but I need to log information such as *"table created"*, *"table dropped"* etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the API you can see the statements being executed by setting the log level of `com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript` to `debug`.

Comment: by adding -X on command line or am i missing something here? I can see on the SQLScript the debug mode but i am not sure how to switch it on when running it.

Comment: Correct. -X will also output this info (and a lot more)

Comment: The -X command line switch works when using the maven plugin, too.